# Optimal way to get time in UTC given today's time as minutes in golang

Tags: optimization, go, time, system-calls

I have  time of the same day in minutes (ie, hours * 60 + minutes) as input ,need to convert it into `time.Time` here is my attempt to do the same .

**Example**

```
Input: 780
Output : 2017-01-29 13:00:51.992871217 +0000 UTC
```

**Code**

```
func MinutesToTime(minutes int) time.Time {
          t := time.Now().UTC() //may be cached  
          h, m, _ := t.Clock()
          diff := minutes - (h*60 + m)
          t = t.Add(time.Duration(diff) * time.Minute)
          return t
}
```

**Doubt**

1. Is there any functions that `time` package exposes that might help
   me optimize this
2. Should i be using gettimeofday() system call directly
3. Would trying to implement vDSO be an overkill , vDSO implementation for only amd64 is found in [go source code](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/964639cc338db650ccadeafb7424bc8ebb2c0f6c/src/runtime/vdso_linux_amd64.go)

**PS**
The  59 sec err is acceptable as minute is my lowest granularity

Comment: do you need, 51.992871217 part?

Comment: Nope, since my input is in minutes +/- 59 secs is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Print(MinutesToTime(780).UTC())
}

func MinutesToTime(m int64) time.Time {
    return time.Unix(time.Now().Unix()/86400*86400+m*60, 0)
}

% go run test.go                                                                                                         
2017-01-29 13:00:00 +0000 UTC%
```

Comment: could you comment on vDSO part as well

Comment: @Sarathsp, sorry, no idea about what vDSO is.